# Tabset panel in flexdashboard storyboard layout

Tags: r, shiny, storyboard, plotly, flexdashboard

I'm trying to include ploly plots in a tabbed html widget within a flexdashboard document with a storyboard layout.  The autosizing of the first plot is fine, but not on any subsequent tab.  Here is an MRE,

````
---
title: "MRE"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    storyboard: true
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
```


### Test

```{r}
plot1 = plot_ly(x = 1:5, y = 6:10, type = "scatter")
plot2 = plot_ly(x = 1:5, y = 1:5, type = "scatter")
tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Employee Monthly", plot1),
    tabPanel("Employee Weekly", plot2)
  )
```
````

Comment: I'm unsure if it's currently possible. See this issue https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/37

Comment: That's what I figured, thanks @LodewicVanTwillert

Comment: Although you can add runtime: shiny , that will easily solve the issue. But I suppose you don't want to use shiny for this storyboard?

Comment: The same issue persists with runtime: shiny.  It looks like both the heights are being manually set rather than filling the containers.

Comment: Using `renderPlot(plot1)` and `renderPlot(plot2)` solves the isse. But you'll need shiny to use `renderPlot()`

Comment: Define CSS height and width for each plot might work without Shiny.